# using A Layout File(.lyt) and fixed width file to create a .CSV file output

Tags: excel, csv, notepad++, fixed-width

I have been given a layout file, .lyt ,which gives me information on how to interpret a fixed width file. I need to convert this file into a comma delimited file. Normally this process is one or two files so i just do it using excels data tools by hand creating the delimitation based on reading the layout and applying it. Now however I have a multiple files with different layout files I need to apply to each and this could become tedious. I remember once seeing someone apply this type of file directly using either notepad ++ or excel but after an exhaustive google search I cannot find a tutorial on how to apply a layout file to a fixed width file to create a csv file without direct human intervention.  Does anyone know how to do this?

below is a sample of what is in the layout file

```
Seq Position    Name            Length
1   1-3         Title Code Full     3
2   4-17        Given Name         14
3   18-18       Middle Initial      1
4   19-48       Surname            30
```

Comment: If you are looking for a Excel formula based approach then you could use the `MID()` function. If you are looking for an Excel-VBA based solution then we'd appreciate you making an effort and start coding yourself and add the current status of your code for the above to your post. If you are looking for an external resource to resolve this issue then this post should be closed as *questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*.

Comment: Note, that Notepad++ itself is unable to apply layout files. But maybe there is a plugin for it to accomplish that. Yet again, that would be off-topic again. If you ask me (personally) then I'd go for an Excel-VBA macro.

Comment: Ah okay, Yes I was looking for a tutorial or if there was a way to apply a .lyt to a fixed width .txt file. I had seen it done once long ago and I didn't think it used any special plug ins in notepad++. basically allowed you to delimit based on the layout file and your choice of delimiter to the txt file to create a .csv It didn't require any coding at all and I cant find it online, If I do find an answer Ill post it for future googlers.

Answer (score 0):

To all future users I could not find a solution but I did find a workaround using excels own data tools. Going to the data tab, go to get external data, From Text. From there follow the wizard. Im sorry I could not find the proper solution I know exists.